# Why is underline style not working for a NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have the following code to try to underline a label's string.

```swift
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello World!")
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

However, when running the code the label shows `Hello World!` with no underline.

I'm running Xcode 12.4, and using an iOS 14.4 iPhone 12 Pro Max simulator.

Comment: `.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue`

Comment: Try with TextView. It will work

Comment: @Kudos There are reasons why using TextView might not be desired in this case.

Comment: @CharlieFish I have faced this too But I ended up using TextView for this bug

Comment: @Kudos Yep, that might be a legit solution. Feel free to post an answer if you want to provide more detail. Likely many ways to solve this issue. Always good to share knowledge in case others run into a similar situation and having multiple answers or options is always helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like this is a bug. Changing the value from `NSUnderlineStyle.single` to `1` fixes the issue.

The final code would look something like the following.

```swift
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello World!")
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: how can i get this answer from somewhere... big thx

Comment: you're holding it wrong. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53149898/428209